# Switching to fullscreen crashes application

Tags: java, libgdx

### Introduction

I’m attempting to switch my application from windowed to fullscreen. Earlier this would have been as easy as making use of [LibGDX](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/)’s `setDisplayMode(Display)`, as well as the same library’s `getDesktopDisplayMode()`. Unfortunately, some things have changed.

### Research

[As of *LibGDX* 1.8.0](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3870)—inside the `Graphics`—what was previously known as `setDisplayMode(DisplayMode)` has been renamed to `setFullScreenMode(DisplayMode)`, as well as what was previously known as `getDesktopDisplayMode()` has been renamed to `getDisplayMode()`.

By then, one might think, that using the renamed methods in the same way as one previously would to switch from windowed to fullscreen would work just as fine:

```
// Tabulator key triggers change from windowed to fullscreen
// The application works fine until that of pressing the tabulator key
if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Keys.TAB))
    Gdx.graphics.setFullscreenMode(Gdx.graphics.getDisplayMode());
```

This doesn’t work fine by any means. As a matter of fact, the application hangs followed by crashing upon pressing the [tabulator key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key).

It’s worth to notice that the `setFullscreenMode(Display)`—[according to the documentation](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Graphics.html#setFullscreenMode-com.badlogic.gdx.Graphics.DisplayMode-)—returns a boolean depending on whether or not the operation was successful. In this case, if you were to put it inside a print statement, you can clearly tell it never returns: even should you let the application be for a while.

#### Moreover

I took a good look around the web—in vain—searching for possible causes of as to why this might be happening. Looking at the release notes of 1.8.0, it truly seems as though all that needs be done is switch from using the previous methods contained by the library to the new ones.

### Question

Does anyone have any insight on as to why the application crashes upon pressing the tabulator key—granted the code following it as shown above is present? Perhas someone could at the very least point me in the right direction?

There’s a fair chance what I’ve concluded is missing out on some important facts.

Comment: You can try to attach your application to a profiler and then dump the memory to see what happened. In windows one would use JMC or Visual JVM or Memory Analyser Tool

Comment: I managed to solve the problem. The solution very much had to do with common sense—it appears after all I was slightly unclear in my post. Perhaps someone can come up with a better name for the question? I’m sure this can be of use for some people in the future.

Comment: That is great. Don't forget to mark your answer as the right one. Sure someone else may face the same problem and for sure this will help.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I’ll make sure to do so—still need to wait the two days before I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

It turns out I’ve managed to be slightly silly!

#### Background

Whenever I create applications—especially games—even though I use libraries such as *LibGDX*, I like to go ahead and create myself a separate thread for handling the game logic. This yields me more control over the application  as a whole—whether it be tick extremely frequently whilst rendering more seldom, or the other way around.

By the way of my logic, the provided code from the question...

```
if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Keys.TAB))
    Gdx.graphics.setFullscreenMode(Gdx.graphics.getDisplayMode());
```

... I decided to put inside the `tick` method. Since that’s inside a separate thread, *LibGDX* probably felt a little left out.

#### Moreover

From my understanding, *LibGDX* handles all its logic inside the `ApplicationAdapter`’s `render` method. That’s where it evaluates all of the user’s actions and makes sure they don’t collide with other things taking place to its own various different components.

For the aforementioned reasons—when I decided to put the “fullscreen logic” inside a separate thread, *LibGDX* crashed. Oh well, at least it works now—That is, by putting the aforementioned code inside the *LibGDX*’s `ApplicationHandler`’s `render` method!